# Make int iterable with forbiddenfruit

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching, forbiddenfruit

I know, this is wrong, but is it possible?
I thought an object is considered an iterable when its `.__iter__` method returned an iterator? So why doesn't this work?

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> def __iter__(self):
...     for i in range(self):
...         yield i
>>> curse(int, "__iter__", __iter__)
>>> for x in 5:
...     print x
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

`int` *does* seem to have an `__iter__` method now:

```
>>> int(5).__iter__
<bound method int.__iter__ of 5>
```

Comment: Note that being explicit will work: `list((5).__iter__())` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Consider reporting a bug to the library.

Comment: Interesting. I can also do `x = (5).__iter__()` and then call `next` on it, it behaves as expected.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm not sure this is the library's fault - the "magic method" is present and working correctly

Comment: Other magic methods are similarly afflicted - I presume this is related to CPython special-casing the built-in classes.

Comment: I thought forbiddenfruit was able to get around that… but I guess not. Disappointing, but probably for the better.

Comment: Did you try as singing `5` to a variable then using that in the for loop?  I'm guessing this doesn't work because you are using an `int` literal.

Comment: I *always* sing to my variables.

Comment: But seriously, no, that's not the problem.

Comment: Haha. Dumb autocorrect!

Comment: Ack, I knew I'd looked at this before. Seems like a waste of an answer :/. Oh well.

Comment: Sorry, didn't find that question when asking. :|

Comment: Old question, but [fishhook](https://pypi.org/project/fishhook/) does this without complaining :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The disassembly of a `for` loop is:

```
import dis

dis.dis("for _ in _: pass")
#>>>   1           0 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 17)
#>>>               3 LOAD_NAME                0 (_)
#>>>               6 GET_ITER
#>>>         >>    7 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 16)
#>>>              10 STORE_NAME               0 (_)
#>>>              13 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
#>>>         >>   16 POP_BLOCK
#>>>         >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#>>>              20 RETURN_VALUE
```

So we want the `GET_ITER` opcode.

```
TARGET(GET_ITER) {
    /* before: [obj]; after [getiter(obj)] */
    PyObject *iterable = TOP();
    PyObject *iter = PyObject_GetIter(iterable);
    Py_DECREF(iterable);
    SET_TOP(iter);
    if (iter == NULL)
        goto error;
    PREDICT(FOR_ITER);
    DISPATCH();
}
```

Which uses `PyObject_GetIter`:

```
PyObject *
PyObject_GetIter(PyObject *o)
{
    PyTypeObject *t = o->ob_type;
    getiterfunc f = NULL;
    f = t->tp_iter;
    if (f == NULL) {
        if (PySequence_Check(o))
            return PySeqIter_New(o);
        return type_error("'%.200s' object is not iterable", o);
    }
    else {
        PyObject *res = (*f)(o);
        if (res != NULL && !PyIter_Check(res)) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                         "iter() returned non-iterator "
                         "of type '%.100s'",
                         res->ob_type->tp_name);
            Py_DECREF(res);
            res = NULL;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

This first checks `t->tp_iter` for nullity.

Now, here's the thing that makes everything click:

```
class X:
    pass

X.__iter__ = lambda x: iter(range(10))

list(X())
#>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

from forbiddenfruit import curse

class X:
    pass

curse(X, "__iter__", lambda x: iter(range(10)))

list(X())
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   File "", line 16, in <module>
#>>> TypeError: 'X' object is not iterable
```

When you set an attribute on a class normally, it calls `PyType_Type->setattro`:

```
static int
type_setattro(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *name, PyObject *value)
{
    if (!(type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE)) {
        PyErr_Format(
            PyExc_TypeError,
            "can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '%s'",
            type->tp_name);
        return -1;
    }
    if (PyObject_GenericSetAttr((PyObject *)type, name, value) < 0)
        return -1;
    return update_slot(type, name);
}
```

See `update_slot`? That goes and updates the slot, so the next call to `GET_ITER` will hit `tp->tp_iter` on `X`. However, `forbiddenfruit` bypasses this process and just injects a dictionary into the class. This means that `PyLong_Type` keeps its default:

```
PyTypeObject PyLong_Type = {
    ...
    0,                                          /* tp_iter */
    ...
};
```

So

```
if (f == NULL)
```

gets triggered,

```
if (PySequence_Check(o))
```

fails (since it's not a sequence) and then it's just

```
return type_error("'%.200s' object is not iterable", o);
```